# Ignore similar values and not treat as duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a Select query in SQL server and I found a question.
When I have two rows like that:

> ```
> ID     Address        City      Zip
> 1   123 Wash Ave.  New York    10035
> 1   123 Wash Ave   New York    10035
> ```

Because I have many same Address but some of them just have dot or some little difference. 
they are almost identical, so how can I find all such case.

Comment: What is the criteria for deciding if this should be ignored or not? One symbol is different? Ignore periods? Ignore something else?

Comment: this is confusing, do you want them to return as duplicates, or do you want them removed?

Comment: you need to use = on the ids and like on the string values and do a  group by the column names and get the rows with having count(*) >1

Answer (score 0):

Using UPS Online API's, our solution was not to correct the error but help sort the results that best represent the correct answer.

With the results returned by UPS, we would run various filters against the original source address and each of the returned responses.  then produce a weighting system to sort the results to present to our CSR to select the most logical "correctly formatted" answer from UPS.

Thus building a score card from the result set, such as the number of digits incorrect in the ZIP Code (catches fat fingering).

Another measure removes all pronunciation marks and gives a ranking of how close the address is now.

Lastly we pass the results through a matrix of standard substitutions [ ST for STREET ] and do a final ranking.

From all these scores we sort and present the results from most likely to least likely to an individual who then selects the correct answer to save in our database.

Correcting these errors now serve two purposes:
1) We look good to our customers by having the correct address information on the billing ( No just close enough)
2) We save on secondary charges from UPS by not being billed for incorrect addresses.